# Installable Web Apps with the Web App Manifest in Chrome for Android not working

Tags: android, json, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Hello i'm getting this error:

```
Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest
```

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "SIMIC project",
  "short_name": "simic",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/simic-bn.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "32x32"
  },
  {
    "src": "images/simic-bn.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "144x144"
  }],
  "start_url": "/wta/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#1e88e5"
}
```

This is my url: "mydomain:8889/wta/" and this is my code structure:

-mydomain

---wta

------css/

------font/

------images/

------js/

------index.html

------manifest.json

What am i missing? THX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for your web app to be installable / be added to the home screen, you need to meet the following requirements:

1. have a web app manifest file with a `short_name`, a `name`, an `icon` and a `start_url` (which you already have)
2. a service worker
3. it must be served over HTTPS

Currently you have the web app manifest file, but you need a service worker. A service worker is basically a Javascript file that intercepts network requests, caches your assets, can send push notifications, etc.

You can create this js file and register your service worker like so:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // register the service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(function(reg){
            console.log("service worker registered");
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error: ", err)
        });
}
```

Note that this should be in the root folder for it to work for the entire site.

Comment: thaks for your answer! I understand what you say, but what do i have to write in my service worker? The code you wrote is just a js file pointing to service worker, isn't it? What does "service-worker.js" contains?

Comment: i followed this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#5 ....i added this:  "self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
 
 
});" in my service work file. It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You also need a service worker script to control your assets, offline-plugin should be a great option!